# ControlP5 Scrollable list start closed

Tags: processing, control-p5

Well i made an scrollable list in processing with the ControlP5 library. 
I need an dropdown and the Dropdown has a lot of deprecated functions in it and there they say this is the way to do it know.

The problem I have is that whenever I run the sketch the scrollable list starts folded out (not just the bar but all the options out).

I initialize the scrolldown list like this

```java
 controlP5.addScrollableList("dropdown")
 .setPosition(0, 0)
 .setSize(200, 100)
 .setBarHeight(10)
 .setItemHeight(10)
 .addItems(l)     
 .setType(ScrollableList.DROPDOWN) 
 ;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of this disconnected snippet that we can't run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set some default 'preselected' option

```
.setValue(1)
```

Or to fold in all options you can set inherited method `setOpen()` so your set up will looks like this

```java
cp5.addScrollableList("dropdown")
     .setPosition(100, 100)
     .setSize(200, 100)
     .setBarHeight(20)
     .setItemHeight(20)
     .addItems(l)
     .setType(ScrollableList.DROPDOWN)
     .setOpen(false)                      //false for closed
     ;
```

Hope it helps to achieve what you want because I'm not sure from your Q.